# How to create children based on parent width

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, carousel

I'm building a carousel in react. The carousel is passed an array of slides and these are cloned as needed depending on how many slides must be shown. This is useful for infinite scrolling for example, where the width of the screen may require more slides than the ones I'm passing to the component. As an example, I can pass 3 slides to the carousel but because the user zoomed out a lot, 10 slides fit the total width, so 10 slides are shown that are just copies of that 3 initial slides.

The main problem I am facing is that when I need to build the cloned slides, I first need the parent component width to know how many I should be creating. The reference to the component at this time hasn't been yet resolved so I can't use it and modify the DOM in the useEffect or useEffectLayout seems not to be the way to go with react. So, how could I get around this?

This is how I use the carousel:

```
<Carrousel startingSlide={0}>
{
    productData.slice(0,slidesCount).map( (o, index)=>{
        let key = "slide-content-"+index;
        return <div key={key} id={key} className="carousel-item">{o.title}</div>
    })
}
</Carrousel>
```

And here how the carousel tries to build the needed cloned slides when rendering:

```
return (
    <section className="carrousel-container" ref={containerRef}>
    {
         children.length ? buildSliderElementsForWidth("HERE I NEED THE CONTAINER WIDTH") : "NO DATA"
    }                
    </section>
);
```

Comment: `useEffect` (and probably `useLayoutEffect`) is the answer. Don't return anything inside the `section` on the first render, pull out the parent width inside the effect, then set it to state before allowing the slides to be rendered and do their own calculations.

Comment: Are you suggesting to defer all redering calculations one render? If this is the case I thought this would produce odd artifacts. I mean, the user seeing nothing and a frame later rendering all the content. Will try it anyway. By the way is there anything builting to "do not render anything first render" or should I go for a simple var that is set first time useEffect is called?

Comment: I don't think you have any other options - if you want the parent dimensions then an effect is the earliest time you can possibly get them. You would have to use a state variable to block rendering on that first render, there's nothing built in for that. If you use `useLayoutEffect` I think the visual inconsistencies will be minimal since it runs before the browser paints anything to the screen, as opposed to `useEffect` which is always after.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I had this plan before posting but I thought I was missing something. I'm pretty new to react.